# Document-Term-Matrix and K-Means

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have a problem with a document term matrix that I try to perform k-means and in the future other algorithms on.

```
str(dtm) leads to:

Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:833268] 433447 439341 443574 449522 453531 465226 
466884 
473543 487479 489550 ...
..@ p       : int [1:4554] 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 ...
..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 820388 4553
..@ Dimnames:List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:820388] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
.. ..$ : chr [1:4553] "m dvi d" "kramer industrie und" " miete carl" "jobag 
business service" ...
..@ x       : num [1:833268] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..@ factors : list()  


dim(dtm)
[1] 820388   4553  


kmeans5 <- kmeans(dtm, 5)
```

If I try to perform kmeans on this dtm this problem appears
"Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod-Fehler 'problem too large' bei Datei ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, Zeile 105"

Since I am new to programming I am not sure, what to do about it.
If more information is needed, please write me. 
Thank You

Comment: `kmeans(as.matrix(dtm), 5)`. Also you probably want to remove some sparse terms first.

Comment: The same problem appears. I don´t know a way to transform a dtm to a matrix, if the dtm is big.

Comment: In order to get good answer more info is probably needed: Can you reproduce the problem with some simple data and script and share in your post?